error NG023 angular module fedration unable to load remote app in host application
``facing the same error i have monoworspace with one nodemodules and same packages for both host and remote app how to fix this.i tried changing packages but didnt work as it has single package file for both host and remote application.
ERROR RuntimeError: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with runInInjectionContext.
